# Variable passed trough state in Link can't update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink, state

I am updating my theme in my App per useState. This is passed to Topbar-Component per prop. console.log() gets triggered every time it changes. From Topbar theme is passed into a link to AboutMe-Copmponent as state, which works, but when i now change the state of theme it only updates in Topbar. I even tried Useeffect. Only when I refresh the site the change is noticed. I read hours about this but I cant solve it somehow.

AppComponent (not all code just the necessary):

```
 function App() {

  const [theme, setTheme] = useState('dark')

  return (
     <Topbar theme={theme}></Topbar>
     <ToggleButton variant='light' onClick={() => setTheme('light')}>Light</ToggleButton>
     <ToggleButton variant='dark' onClick={() => setTheme('dark')}>Dark</ToggleButton>
```

TopbarComponent:

```
    export default function Topbar({theme}) {
console.log('Topbar',theme)
React.useEffect(()=>{
  console.log('changed')
},[theme])
```

Output when I press the buttons:
Topbar light
changed
Topbar dark
changed

AboutMeComponent:

```
export default function AboutMe() {
const location = useLocation()
console.log(location.state)
React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('About-Me',location.state)
},[location])
```

Initial output:
dark
About-Me dark

When I now press the other Button I only get the Topbar Output
Only when refreshing I get the AboutMe Outputs again.

PS
The theme is changed anyway from dark to light but i need this state to change fonts etc.

Comment: Why can't you use the state from `App`?

Comment: The Link to AboutMe is in Topbar Component, but I have already tried everything from App

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest sticking with documentation's recommendation which is to use `useContext` for very this example of setting theme using context.

Check out: https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useContext

Usage : Passing data deeply into the tree

```
 import { useContext } from 'react';

  function Button() {
   const theme = useContext(ThemeContext);
```

useContext returns the context value for the context you passed. To determine the context value, React searches the component tree and finds the closest context provider above for that particular context.

To pass context to a Button, wrap it or one of its parent components into the corresponding context provider:

```
function MyPage() {
  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value="dark">
      <Form />
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
}

function Form() {
  // ... renders buttons inside ...
}
```

It doesn’t matter how many layers of components there are between the provider and the Button. When a Button anywhere inside of Form calls useContext(ThemeContext), it will receive "dark" as the value.

Answer (score 0):

I have it working now with the useContext hook. Thank you i somehow forgot about it.

App:

```
       export const ThemeContext = React.createContext()

function App() {

  const [theme, setTheme] = useState('black')
  console.log(theme)

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{backgroundColor:theme}}>
      <BrowserRouter>
      <div className='App' id={theme}>
        <Topbar/>
        <div className="position-absolute top-0 start-0">
          <ToggleButton variant='light' onClick={() => setTheme('white')}>Light</ToggleButton>
          <ToggleButton variant='dark' onClick={() => setTheme('black')}>Dark</ToggleButton>
        </div>
```

```
Topbar:

export default function Topbar() {
    const {user,logout} = UserAuth()
    const [error, setError] = useState('')
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const style = useContext(ThemeContext)
    console.log(style)
```

AboutMe:

```
export default function AboutMe() {
const style = useContext(ThemeContext)
console.log(style)



return (
    <>
    <div className='d-flex' style={style}>
```

I had to move my Routing from Index.js to App.js because it had to be wrapped in the Context provider, but now my theme gets passed into every single component.